# Using SQL Date Functions to Automate a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to check invoice information with a range of dates.

**i.e.: 07-01-2013 to 07-31-2013**.

I normally would use a select query with the **between** function. But now I want to have the system recognize a range automatically based on the system date. I need the query to basically think like this. Today is August 2. I have to grap all the invoices that fall between August 1st and 2nd. In 10 days from now. The system will still recognize it's August and give me the invoices that fall between August 1st and 12th. Can this be done through Date functions? Also; I have to have the same logic for prior year periods too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily with date math.

```
select *
from mytable
where 
    dt >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0) --Beg of current month
    and dt < DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)) --Beg. of next month
```

Prior Periods:

```
select *
from mytable
where 
    dt >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)) --Beg last month
    and dt < DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0) --Beg current month
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateColumn >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)
AND DateColumn <= DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE YourDateColumn Between DATEADD(d, -1 * DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()) And GETDATE()
```

Will get you the 1st through today